# Assign a 2-column pandas DataFrame to a Series such that the first column is the index of the Series and the second column is the data does not work

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

1. Given a dataset

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Runner": ["Runner1", "Runner2", "Runner3", "Runner4"], "distance":[2,1,0,1]})
```

2. I first remove the 0s.

```
df = df[df["Runner"] > 0]
```

3. I assign df["distance] as the parameter *data* and df["Runner] as parameter *index* of a new Series *ser1*

```
ser1 = pd.Series(data=df["distance"], index=df[df["Runner"])
```

Here is how ser1 looks -

```
Runner  
Runner1   NaN  
Runner2   NaN  
Runner4   NaN  
Name: distance, dtype: float64
```

I expected ser1 to show

```
Runner  
Runner1    2  
Runner2    1  
Runner4    1  
Name: distance, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the zero's use

```
df = df[df["distance"] > 0]
```

then

```
df['distance'].index = df['Runner']
ser1 = df['distance']
```

- output

```
Runner
Runner1    2
Runner2    1
Runner4    1
Name: distance, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
df = df[df["distance"] > 0]
ser1 = pd.Series(data=df["distance"].values, index=df["Runner"])
```

But the ideal way to do it is:

```
ser1 = df[df["distance"] > 0].set_index('Runner')['distance']
```

Output:

```
Runner
Runner1    2
Runner2    1
Runner4    1
Name: distance, dtype: int64
```